# Can docker application use dependent images?

Tags: image, docker, containers

We have an application that use jvm and python runtime and some other libraries.
As our view, jvm and python runtime and these libraries are our application dependent components.

We use docker as our development environment, but current docker release(1.5) seem to only supports streamline-base image building style, that we must specify all our dependent libraries in our dockerfile.

Is it possible to specify these libraries when we execute docker run command?

In our application example (suppose we build some docker images previously: jvm, python, lib1, lib2...)

We want to execute app. by $docker run --dep_img=jvm --dep_img=python --dep_img=lib1 --dep_img=lib2 our_app_image

Possible?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: No. The idea behind a Docker image is a static containerized app, with all its dependencies inside. There are some workarounds you can face the issue and solve it:

1. Having different images/tags for each dependency (or group of dependencies). Personally I think this is the approach you should try to follow. Organize the images and dependencies you have and create one image for each possible dependency group you can have.
2. Have a init script in you docker image that installs the dependencies each time you create a container. This script can get the dependencies through arguments to the script or using environmental variables. Use this approach if you have a very large number of possible scenarios of dependencies.

Comment: Thanks, I know the docker image is static.

In our case, when the OS or any dependent libraries, we are forced to rebuild our application image again and again.

The docker application image is just like tradition application image(ex: a.out).
 
Traditional application can use static link and dynamic link to produce its image, so we think docker should support both ways to form docker image.

The dynamic approach may be like: docker run --dep=x --dep=y run_img